# i am trying write a worker in rails using resque for background jobs

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, resque

hello i am new to rails i want to create a worker in my rails application, using resque for background jobs.
The worker has to run a python script located in my home directory.

```
class DataCollector
  @queue = :data_collection_queue

  def self.perform(*args)
    redis = Redis.new(:host => Figaro.env.redis_host, :port => Figaro.env.redis_port, :password => Figaro.env.redis_password)
      system("exec '/usr/home/hello.py'")
  end
end
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: even after scheduling an creating a worker it is not reflected in my resque web concole.